# Images in Android ActionBar Spinner are Large

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, spinner, android-menu

I have an image spinner in my Android action bar, but when I click it, the images are not scaled down. This is a screenshot of my application: [image]

Here is my spinner layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerInside" >
    </ImageView>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is the item declaration in menu.xml:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_spinner"
    android:actionViewClass="android.widget.Spinner"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="Share"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `wrap_content` instead of `match_parent` for `ImageView` in both `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` as below...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerInside" >
    </ImageView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I tried this solution and it did not change anything. The "share" buttons are still the same size.

Comment: you can fixed the size of `LinearLayout` to `100dip` of anything else...and then set `match_parent` to `ImageView`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe someone could give an comprehensive answer, but you need to use resource filtering for screen dpi.

E.g "drawable-mdpi", "drawable-hdpi"

Just place appropriate(scaled) sizes inside folders

**Edit:**

Alright i tried similar layout

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffff920f">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/main_spinner_item_imageview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/abc_ic_cab_done_holo_light"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

in a sample project and everything worked fine. As i mentioned before you need to scale your icon for screen dpi. There is a folder - size list below

- "drawable-mdpi", 32x32
- "drawable-hdpi", 48x48
- "drawable-xhdpi", 72x72
- "drawable-xxhdpi", 96x96

For more sample, see Action Bar Icon Pack [here](https://developer.android.com/design/downloads/index.html)

Comment: Ok. What are the different icon sizes? Could you point me to some place that has size specifications for action bar items? Thanks!